# java streams: How to apply a reduce method

Tags: java, java-stream

I'd like to change this code in order to make it more elegant:

```
List<Criteria> filters = new ArrayList<Criteria>();

if (null != searchForm.getScope()) {
    List<Criteria> scopeCriteria = this.getApplications(searchForm.getScope())
        .stream()
        .map(app -> Criteria.where("appCreation").is(app.getCode()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    <<<< HOW TO APPLY A REDUCE METHOD ON scopeCriteria >>>
    if (!scopeCriteria.isEmpty()) {
        if (scopeCriteria.size() == 1) {
            filters.add(scopeCriteria.get(0));
        }
        else {
            Criteria crit = new Criteria();
            filters.add(crit.orOperator(scopeCriteria.toArray(new Criteria[scopeCriteria.size()])));
        }
    }
    else {
        filters.add(Criteria.where("appCreation").is("unknown"));
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to get is:

1. Get current scopes on database: `this.getApplications(searchForm.getScope())`
2. For each `app` build an `Criteria`.
3. Populate criterias on `scopeCriteria` to `filters`.

I feel really noisy with this code, I was thinking about using `Optional` and some other stream features, but I don't quite figure out how to get that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your stream code already looks pretty streamlined to me (no pun intended).  Off the top of my head, maybe you could combine the `if` and `else` conditions when adding filters, and just the `else` code, even if there be just a single filter.

Comment: Isn't this question a better fit for CodeReview?

Comment: What is wrong with a `orOperator` with 1 `Criteria`? That would simplify it as well.

Comment: I was thinking for example to apply a reduce method on scopeCriteria...

Comment: Perhaps: `Criteria[] scopeCriteria = this.getApplications(searchForm.getScope())
        .stream()
        .map(app -> Criteria.where("appCreation").is(app.getCode())).toArray(Criteria[]::new); if (scopeCriteria.length == 1) {filters.add(scopeCriteria[0]);} else if (scopeCriteria.length > 1) {filters.add(new Criteria().orOperator(scopeCriteria));} else {filters.add(Criteria.where("appCreation").is("unknown"));}`

But I agree with @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty clean a context, but what about this one? As I can see, that `List<Criteria> filters` contains only one element.

```
public static Criteria getFiltersByCriteria(Scope scope, Criteria criteria) {
    if (scope == null)
        return null;

    Criteria[] scopeCriteria = getApplications(scope).stream()
                                                     .map(app -> criteria.is(app.getCode()))
                                                     .toArray(Criteria[]::new);

    if (scopeCriteria.length == 0)
        return Criteria.where("appCreation").is("unknown");
    if (scopeCriteria.length == 1)
        return scopeCriteria[0];
    return new Criteria().orOperator(scopeCriteria);
}
```

Comment: Well, this is old part from version with list.

Comment: Well, in case of a `List`, I’d still use `get(0)` instead of `iterator() .next()`…